# How to do overlapping cluster analysis in Matlab or R?

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means, fuzzy, hierarchical-clustering

I have a binary matrix of size 20 by 300. I want to cluster the 20 variables into five or six groups. So far I used kmeans and hierarchical clustering algorithms in matlab with different distance metrics but both give me non-overlapping clusters. I see on my data that some of the variables should be located in more than one group. Does anyone know if there is a way to do overlapping clusters either in matlab ot R? Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Fuzzy clustering in MATLAB documentation http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/fuzzy/fp310.html

Comment: Thank you Ali. It seems this is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

look for Weka4OC (java) or  ADPROCLUS(R) which are able to build overlapping clusters